# In ubuntu OS when i try to upload file, automatically project root path added by own

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I' try to upload file from .net core application, it is working fine with windows OS,
but when i try to run a.net core application in ubuntu OS,
In this while uploading file in perticular folder, application add its root path automatically.

Here is my code as bellow

```cs
var Image = editProfile.PostedFile;
if (Image != null)
{
    var Extension = Path.GetExtension(Image.FileName);
    var FileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + Extension;
    var SaveFileName = Settings.UserProfilePhotoPath + FileName;

    var FilePath = Settings.DisplayCompanyLogo() + "/" + FileName;
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await Image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    editProfile.CompanyLogo = SaveFileName;
}
else
{
    editProfile.CompanyLogo = null;
}
```

Comment: Which directory should your app be using when uploading a file? Also, I would not combine paths the way that you are doing on line 7 (var FilePath), I would use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-2.0) as it is implemented in an Operating System agnostic way.

Comment: What do you mean by _"application add its root path automatically"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster application root path means "location on the disk where my project is stored"

Comment: @JamieTaylor, Yes i have already tried with Path.Combine(), but still it gives me same path as Path. My expected path : "http://192.168.1.183:60318/wwwroot/Content/images/CompanyLogo/636969841976160322.png", path what i'm getting in exception "Could not find a part of the path '/mnt/2C94787F94784CF8/Pravin KegTools 21-06-2019/20-06-2019/KegTools/KegToolsSubAdmin/http:/192.168.1.183:60318/wwwroot/Content/images/CompanyLogo/636969841976160322.png'." This is what i'm getting

Comment: Let me rephrase that. Mention, in your question, the expected and actual paths. As far as I understand from your comment, you're trying to save a file to a `FilePath` starting with `http://`. You can't do that using `FileStream()`.

Comment: @AzimKazi what are you expecting the FilePath to look like?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I'm expecting this path http:/192.168.1.183:60318/wwwroot/Content/images/CompanyLogo/636969841976160322.png'

Comment: You cannot upload to HTTP with `FileStream()`. You have your requirements mixed up, this is an XY problem. Explain what you want to do, don't explain what non-working solution you want to work.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have two asp.net core application, 1. WEB api, 2. Admin, both are different solution, now i want to store the uploaded image from Admin to folder of WEB api project, so how can i do this.